# I have some issues in my login form,how to resolve it?

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

**I put in the information and click "Submit Query" to log in, it redirects me to a blank page**.

- I have already registered with the information im trying to login.
- And checked in the database if the user exists. This is the code:

  ```
  <?php
  // ERROR DEBUG THINGY
  $showErrors = (isset($_GET['debug'])) ? true : false;

  if(!$showErrors) {
      ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
  }
  else {
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
  }

  // DATABASE START
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username) or die (mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db("test", $conn);

  // WE START THE SESSION
  session_start();

  // START LOGIN PROCESS
  if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
      print_secure_content(); //CONTENT THAT'S ECHOED ONCE YOU LOG IN
  }
  else {
      if(!$_SESSION['logging']) {       //IF LOGGING SESSION ISNT RUNNING
          $_SESSION['logging'] = true; //RETURNS THE USER BACK TO THE LOGIN FORM
          loginform();                //SHOWS THE LOGIN FORM
      }
      else if($_SESSION['logging']) {
          $numberOfRows = checkpass(); //CHECK IF THE USER ALREADY EXISTS
          if($numberOfRows == 1) {    //IF OLD USER LOG HIM IN
              $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['username'];
              $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
              echo "<h1> You have logged in successfully </h1>";
              print_secure_content();
              print_user_details();
          }
          else {
              echo "You have entered a wrong username or password, please try again.<br />";
              loginform();
          }
      }
  }

  // DATABASE CLOSE
  mysql_close();

  // FUNCTIONS!!!

  function loginform() { //THE LOG IN FORM
      echo "Please login <br />
      <form method=\"POST\" action=\"?\">
              USERNAME<br />
              <input name='username' type='text'><br />
              PASSWORD<br />
              <input name='password' type='password'><br />
      <input type='submit' name='login'></form>
      <p><a href='registerform.php'> Register Here! </a></hr>";
  }

  function print_user_details() { //CHECK PASSWORD
      if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$_POST['username']}' and password = '{$_POST['password']}'";
          $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
          return mysql_num_rows($result);
      }
  }

  function checkpass() { //CHECK PASSWORD
      if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$_POST['username']}' and password = '{$_POST['password']}'";
          $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die (mysql_error());
          return mysql_num_rows($result);
      }
  }

  function print_secure_content() { // ECHO ONCE YOU LOG IN
      echo 'Hello '. $_SESSION['id'] .'!<br />';
      echo 'Only a logged in user can see this. <br /> <a href="logout.php"> Logout </a>';
  }
  ```

  ?>

Comment: Check the apache error logs to check if PHP is printing anything to that?

Comment: And you can use your browser WEB development tools to see if any error HTTP headers are returned.

Comment: `session_start()` should be at the top.

Comment: Additionally you should be using mysqli_* instead of mysql_ as its depreciated and insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be some syntax Error.
Go to **php.ini** file
Change **display_errors=off** to **on** and save it.
 Restart the server
Check in Front end. You might find the Error. Correct it.
Again Restart the Server to see your changes.

Comment: did u restart Apache?

Comment: If stopping it and running it again from XAMPP restarts it, then yes, checked php.ini again and it says display_errors=On

Comment: Ok.. For instance remove your // ERROR DEBUG THINGY if, else.  And try what i have said above...

Comment: Ok it gives me a notice and a warning.

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 68

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 68

Comment: Ok fine.. What i observed was.
Your $conn holds mysql_connect(); in line 16. and you are closing your DB mysql_close(); at line 48. And at line 66 you have used $conn variable which holds nothing. bcoz u have already closed your DB.

Comment: Ok i have done that, but it still gives me the same notice and warning for some reason

Comment: function print_user_details() and function checkpass() both use the same line $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '{$_POST['username']} and password = '{$_POST['password']}'"; but it only says that the function checkpass() has the error

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '".$_POST['username']."' and password = '".$_POST['password']."'";

user sql query like this

Comment: Tried doing that but nothing has changed.